# Numerically solving an ODE whose right-hand side involves an integral

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

In [a 1955 paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01343351) on surfaces of constant negative Gaussian curvature, Marc-Henri Amsler defines a function $w(x)$ by giving the ordinary differential equation
$$w'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \sin(w(t))dt,$$
with the initial condition $w(0)=\pi/2$.  So the slope $w'(x)$ is the average value of $\sin(w(x))$ over the interval $[0..x]$.  In particular, we have $w'(0)=\sin(\pi/2)=1$.

I asked Mathematica to compute $w(x)$ for me numerically by using `NDSolve`:

```
NDSolve[{w'[x] == NIntegrate[Sin[w[t]], {t, 0, x}]/x, w[0] == Pi/2}, w[x],
             {x, -2, 2}]
```

but Mathematica (version 10.0.2) responds with a slew of errors, the first batch of which repeatedly report that

```
NIntegrate::nlim: t = x is not a valid limit of integration. >>
```

Is this ODE outside of Mathematica's region of expertise, or I am doing something stupid in how I have phrased my Mathematica request?

Comment: That $w(x)$ is a Painlevé transcendent in disguise, which comes from solving the sine-Gordon equation. The difficulties encountered in the two answers below are well-known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being a mathematician, I resist fudging by cutting off the singularity by some small `eps = 10^-12`.  But if you're an engineer, you should be satisfied [@Nasser's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) answer, which likely yields single-precision accuracy, which is pretty good after all.

A little analysis shows
$$\eqalign{
w''(x) &= -{1\over x^2} \int_0^x \sin w(t) \; dt + {\sin w(x) \over x} \cr
 &=  \int_0^x {\sin w(x) - \sin w(t) \over x^2} \; dt \cr
 &= \int_0^x {(x-t) \over x^2}{\sin w(x) - \sin w(t) \over x-t} \; dt \cr
 &\buildrel \rm{MVT} \over = \int_0^x {(x-t) \over x^2}\,\cos w(\xi) \, w'(\xi)\,(x-t)  \; dt \cr
 &= \int_0^x {\left(1-{t\over x}\right)^2}\,\cos w(\xi) \, w'(\xi)  \; dt \cr
}$$
where $\xi = \xi_t$ is between $x$ and $t$ and depends on $t$ for a fixed $x$. Of the three factors in the integrand as $x \rightarrow 0$, the first lies between $0$ and $1$, the cosine approaches zero since $w(\xi) \rightarrow \pi/2$, and $w'(\xi)$ approaches $1$.  Therefore $w''(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.
Thus we should define our ODE so that $w''(0) = 0$.  [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) is the tool for that.

```
sol = NDSolve[{w''[x] == Piecewise[{{(Sin[w[x]] - w'[x])/x, x != 0}}],
     w[0] == Pi/2, w'[0] == 1}, w, {x, 0, 4 Pi}];
Plot[w[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It differs from Nasser's answer by less than `3 * 10^-8` over the interval.

Answer (score 6):

There is a singularity at `x=0`.

First, differentiate and use Leibniz rule, this gives the non-linear ODE

$$
   x w''(x)+ w'(x) = \sin(w(x))
$$

But `NDSolve` can't solve this due to singularity at $x=0$

```
eq = x w''[x] + w'[x] == Sin[w[x]];
NDSolve[{eq, w[0] == Pi/2, w'[0] == 1}, w, {x, 0, 1}]
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.
```

So using trick to bypass $x=0$ (maybe a better trick exists, but the idea is to avoid zero)

```
sol = With[{eps = 10^-12},
  NDSolve[{w''[x] == 
     If[x < eps, -w'[x]/eps + Sin[w[x]]/eps, -w'[x]/x + Sin[w[x]]/x], 
    w[0] == Pi/2, w'[0] == 1}, w, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
  ];
Plot[w[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent ODE (as given by @Nasser) can be solved by [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) when using the `{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}` [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    x w''[x] + w'[x] == Sin[w[x]],
    w[0] == Pi/2,
    w'[0] == 1
    },
    w,
    {x, 0, 12},
    Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}
];

Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 12}, AxesOrigin -> {0,0}]
```

[image]